# Python Tkinter grid set up

Tags: python, tkinter

My first coding project, and I am trying to create an app to use as a dashboard on an old laptop.

[Weather app concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0RD3.png)

Can I use tkinters grid to create boxes like in the picture?

I have stumbled for two days and I cannot come up with a good result at all nor have I managed to create a good box yet.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



def weather():
    city=city_listbox.get()
    url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=*myappid*&units=metric".format(city)
    res=requests.get(url)
    output=res.json()

weather_status=output['weather'][0]['description']
temperature=output['main']['temp']
feelslike=output['main']['feels_like']
humidity=output['main']['humidity']
wind_speed=output['wind']['speed']

weather_status_label.configure(text="Weather status : "+ weather_status)

if weather_status=="few clouds":
    partial_cloud_label=Label(image=partial_cloud)
    partial_cloud_label.grid(row=3, column=4)
    

temperature_label.configure(text="Temperature : "+ str(temperature) +"°C")

feelslike_label.configure(text="Feels like : "+ str(feelslike) +"°C")

humidity_label.configure(text="Humidity : "+ str(humidity) +"%")

wind_speed_label.configure(text="Wind speed  : "+ str(wind_speed) +"m/s")




window=Tk()
window.geometry("1920x1080")
window.iconbitmap('localfile')
window.title('Show dis weather')

partial_cloud=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("local file"))
day_clear=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("localfile"))
cloudy=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("localfile"))

city_name_list=["City1", "City2"]

city_listbox=StringVar(window)
city_listbox.set("select the city")
option=OptionMenu(window,city_listbox,*city_name_list)
option.grid(row=2,column=6,padx=150,pady=10)

b1=Button(window,text="Select",width=15,command=weather)
b1.grid(row=5,column=6,padx=150)

weather_status_label=Label(window, font=("didot",15,"bold"))
weather_status_label.grid(row=10,column=6)

temperature_label=Label(window,font=("didot",15,"bold"))
temperature_label.grid(row=16,column=6)

feelslike_label=Label(window,font=("didot",15,"bold"))
feelslike_label.grid(row=22,column=6)

humidity_label=Label(window,font=("didot",15,"bold"))
humidity_label.grid(row=28,column=6)

wind_speed_label=Label(window,font=("didot",15,"bold"))
wind_speed_label.grid(row=34,column=6)


window.mainloop()
```

Seeking advice towards Tkinter gui.
I was thinking that you could possibly create boxes and set all the "widgets" or data inside them.

For e.x, creating a box and put it to the left and have the weather status and information inside there. A box NW for the buttons to choose city. Box N to show big text for which city it is showing information for.

Is this possible in Tkinter?

If I have left insufficient information or if this is a too loose thread to being helped through, please write and tell me about it, I am very new in this, so I appreciate all help.

With Regards!

Comment: Use canvas and grid it in the correct place

Comment: @PCM Why use a canvas? If you are only going to use widgets, there is no point in putting them all in a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Frames in order to organize the view.
And instead of using random bigger numbers to try spacing things out(empty rows and columns stay at size zero until filled with content), you should take a look into the `weight` option of `grid.row(or column)configure` as well as the `row(or column)span` option of `grid` itself.

in order to achieve your view you might wanna start with something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        #Window config
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "WeatherApp")
        self.geometry("1920x1080")
        
        #Main Layout
        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.pack(fill="both", expand = True)
        self.mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        
        #Top Container
        self.top = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.top.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4)
        
        #configure layout for top view
        self.top.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.top.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        #content of top view
        self.toplabel = tk.Label(self.top, text = "City: ")
        self.toplabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        #day1
        self.day1 = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        
        #configure layout for top view
        self.day1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.day1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        #content of day1 frame
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.day1, text="saturday")
        self.label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        
        #day2
        self.day2 = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        
        #you don't have to configure if all cells should have equal size
        
        #content of day1 frame
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.day2, text="sunday")
        self.label2.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        
        #day3
        self.day3 = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day3.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        
        #content of day1 frame
        self.label3 = tk.Label(self.day3, text="monday")
        self.label3.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        
        #day4
        self.day4 = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day4.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        
        #content of day1 frame
        self.label4 = tk.Label(self.day4, text="tuesday")
        self.label4.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

EDIT:

The `__init__` function is always getting called when a class is being used, [see](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_class_init.asp). You can use other functions from within each other, but you can't just toss it in there and expect it to run without beeing called, you might wanna take a look at [inner Functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-inner-functions/).

But that isn't what I would do in your case.

I would create 2 new other classes (1 for top frame, 1 for bottom frame) and inhereting from the `tk.Frame` class for 2 reasons:

1. readability since everything is where it belongs and nicely grouped togehter
2. reuseability because the content of all your bottom frames is the same(widget wise) so you can just pass the values to change:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        #Window config
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "WeatherApp")
        self.geometry("1920x1080")
        
        #Main Layout
        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.pack(fill="both", expand = True)
        self.mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        
        #Top Container
        #note the changed declaration, since we're now calling 
        #our own Frame class
        self.top = TopFrame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.top.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4)
        
        
        #day1
        # note the passthrough of the day argument
        self.day1 = DayFrame(self.mainframe, "saturday")
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        
        
        #day2
        self.day2 = DayFrame(self.mainframe, "sunday")
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        
        
        #day3
        self.day3 = DayFrame(self.mainframe, "monday")
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day3.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        
        
        #day4
        self.day4 = DayFrame(self.mainframe, "tuesday")
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day4.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        
     
     
class TopFrame(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        #add code for your widgets in top frame here
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Top Frame")
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        
class DayFrame(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, day):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        # add code for bottom frame widgets here
        # pass nessecary variables through to reuse the code
        self.day = day
        self.daylabel = tk.Label(self, text = day)
        self.daylabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        
        
app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Also please note what thelizzard said about my sloppiness when it comes to using `.grid(row=0, column=0)` in the same row, because you will run into errors with this as soon as you want to change anything about the variable!

Comment: Please never use `<variable name> = <widget>(...).grid(...)`. It can confuse people and you get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) kind of problem.

Comment: just threw that in to have some content, but you're right, changed it

Comment: @newb Can I write to you personally somehow, to get advice with the code?

Comment: just ask a new question if you have one @Joggster

Comment: Hi there @newb I have edited my comment with my new question, could you possibly check it? I am trying to implement the weather code inside your tKinter grid code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Newb, and you others, for different answers.

I have used Newb's code and made some changes, like making it a 12 grid big and changing the order of where the frames should be.

I have also tried to implement the "weather" code from the original code, and there is where I got stuck.

Can you put a function inside another function?

I still cannot understand what init is for, but that I can learn on the side.

Here is the updated code:

```
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class Application(tk.Tk):
   
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        #Window config
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "WeatherApp")
        self.geometry("1920x1080")
        self.iconbitmap('localfile')
        #This part I have added
        self.partial_cloud=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("localfile"))
        self.day_clear=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("localfile"))
        self.cloudy=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("localfile"))


        #This part I have added
        def weather():
            self.city=city_listbox.get()
            self.url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=*myappid*&units=metric".format(city)
            self.res=requests.get(url)
            self.output=res.json()

            self.weather_status=output['weather'][0]['description']
            self.temperature=output['main']['temp']
            self.feelslike=output['main']['feels_like']
            self.humidity=output['main']['humidity']
            self.wind_speed=output['wind']['speed']

            self.weather_status_label.configure(text="Weather status : "+ weather_status)

                if weather_status=="few clouds":
                    partial_cloud_label=Label(image=partial_cloud)
                    partial_cloud_label.grid(row=3, column=4)
        


            temperature_label.configure(text="Temperature : "+ str(temperature) +"°C")

            feelslike_label.configure(text="Feels like : "+ str(feelslike) +"°C")

            humidity_label.configure(text="Humidity : "+ str(humidity) +"%")

            wind_speed_label.configure(text="Wind speed  : "+ str(wind_speed) +"m/s")




        #Main Layout
        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.pack(fill="both", expand = True)
        self.mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        
        #Top Left Container
        self.tl = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.tl.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        #configure layout for top view
        self.tl.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tl.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        



        #This part I have added

        #content of top view
        self.city_name_list=["city1", "city2"]

        self.city_listbox=StringVar(self.tl)
        self.city_listbox.set("select the city")
        self.option=OptionMenu(self.tl,city_listbox,*city_name_list)
        self.option.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=150,pady=10)

        self.b1=Button(self.tl, text="Select",width=15,command=weather)
        self.b1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=150)
        #self.tllabel = tk.Label(self.tl, text = "Button ", font=("Sentinel", 20, "bold"))
        #self.tllabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)







        #Top Middle Container (tm)
        self.tm = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.tm.grid(row = 0, column = 1) #Leaving comment for my self columnspan = 4
        
        #configure layout for top view
        self.tm.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tm.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        #content of top view
        self.tmlabel = tk.Label(self.tm, text = "City: ", font=("Sentinel", 36, "bold"))
        self.tmlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


        #Left Container
        self.left = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.left.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        
        #configure layout for top view
        self.left.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.left.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        #content of top view
        self.leftlabel = tk.Label(self.left, text = "Weather ", font=("Sentinel", 20, "bold"))
        self.leftlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


        

        
        #day1
        self.day1 = tk.Frame(self.mainframe) # Tried to make a border, leaving comment for my self width=3, height=100, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1) #bd=100)#relief=tk.RIDGE)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        
        #configure layout for top view
        self.day1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.day1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        #content of day1 frame
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.day1, text="Saturday", font=("Sentinel", 26, "bold")).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        
        #day2
        self.day2 = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        
        #you don't have to configure if all cells should have equal size
        
        #content of day1 frame
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.day2, text="Sunday", font=("Sentinel", 26, "bold")).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        
        #day3
        self.day3 = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day3.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        
        #content of day1 frame
        self.label3 = tk.Label(self.day3, text="Monday", font=("Sentinel", 26, "bold")).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        
        #day4
        self.day4 = tk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day4.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
        
        #content of day1 frame
        self.label4 = tk.Label(self.day4, text="Tuesday", font=("Sentinel", 26, "bold")).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

You have already helped me a lot, but if you feel to help me how to implement this, feel free to do it.

Thanks and have a great day!

EDIT:

Hi there!
Sorry for bumping an old thread, I am still working to make this application working!

**When I am  trying to run the following code, I get the NameError: "name 'city_listbox' is not defined code" at line 172**

Anyone has any energy and clue what I can do to implement the Weather code inside the grid code supplied from Newb?

```
import requests
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class Application(tk.Tk):
   
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        def weather():
           def __init__(self, TopLFrame):
               city=city_listbox.get()
               url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=ID&units=metric".format(city)
               res=requests.get(url)
               output=res.json()

               weather_status=output['weather'][0]['description']
               temperature=output['main']['temp']
               feelslike=output['main']['feels_like']
               humidity=output['main']['humidity']
               wind_speed=output['wind']['speed']

               weather_status_label.configure(text="Weather status : "+ weather_status)

               if weather_status=="few clouds":
                   partial_cloud_label=tk.Label(image=partial_cloud)
                   partial_cloud_label.grid(row=3, column=4)
        


               temperature_label.configure(text="Temperature : "+ str(temperature) +"°C")

               feelslike_label.configure(text="Feels like : "+ str(feelslike) +"°C")

               humidity_label.configure(text="Humidity : "+ str(humidity) +"%")

               wind_speed_label.configure(text="Wind speed  : "+ str(wind_speed) +"m/s") 

        #Window config
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "WeatherApp")
        self.geometry("1920x1080")
        #self.iconbitmap('linktopicture')
        
        #self.partial_cloud=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("linktopicture"))
        #self.day_clear=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("linktopicture"))
        #self.cloudy=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("linktopicture"))
        
  
        #Main Layout
        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.pack(fill="both", expand = True)
        self.mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        
  
        #Top Left Container
        self.tl = TopLFrame(self.mainframe, weather)
        self.tl.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        #self.tl.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #self.tl.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        #Top Middle Container (tm)
        self.tm = TopMFrame(self.mainframe)
        self.tm.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        
        #self.tm.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #self.tm.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        

        #Left Container
        self.left = MidFrame(self.mainframe)
        self.left.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        
        #self.left.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #self.left.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
       
        
        
        #day1
        self.day1 = BottomFrame(self.mainframe, "Monday") 
        self.day1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        
        #self.day1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #self.day1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
   
        #day2
        self.day2 = BottomFrame(self.mainframe, "saturday")
        #placing in the main frame
        self.day2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        

        #day3
        self.day3 = BottomFrame(self.mainframe, "test")
        self.day3.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        
        #day4
        self.day4 = BottomFrame(self.mainframe, "test2")
        self.day4.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
        
    



class TopMFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #add code for your widgets in top frame here
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Top Mid Frame")
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
 


class TopLFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, Application):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        self.city_name_list=["City1", "City2"]

        self.city_listbox=tk.StringVar(self)
        self.city_listbox.set("select the city")
        
        self.option=tk.OptionMenu(self, city_listbox, *city_name_list)
        self.option.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=150,pady=10)

        self.b1=tk.Button(self, text="Select",width=15,command=weather)
        self.b1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=150)

class MidLFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Left Frame")
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.weather_status_label=tk.Label(self, font=("didot",15,"bold"))
        self.weather_status_label.grid(row=10,column=6)

        self.temperature_label=tk.Label(self,font=("didot",15,"bold"))
        self.temperature_label.grid(row=16,column=6)

        self.feelslike_label=tk.Label(self,font=("didot",15,"bold"))
        self.feelslike_label.grid(row=22,column=6)

        self.humidity_label=tk.Label(self,font=("didot",15,"bold"))
        self.humidity_label.grid(row=28,column=6)

        self.wind_speed_label=tk.Label(self,font=("didot",15,"bold"))
        self.wind_speed_label.grid(row=34,column=6)

class BottomFrame(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, day):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        # add code for bottom frame widgets here
        # pass nessecary variables through to reuse the code
        self.day = day


        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text = day, font=("Sentinel", 26, "bold"))
        self.label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

With Regards,
Joggster!

Comment: you defined the variable self.city_listbox but your calling city_listbox which doesnt exist, hence the name error, just add self. in order to fix that

Comment: also when you want to interact with an element from another class (function or widget) you need to call by `Class.element` You should take a look at Object Oriented Programming in order to be able to debug your program

Comment: Thanks a lot @newb, did not notice that part that I had forgotten to add ".self". 
I will also study more about Object-Oriented Programming! 
With Regards